# in angular my content is being fetched from api the content has inline style css. and i am using innerHTML="variable". styling is not working

Tags: html, css, angular

> this is my html component file allData has data from db with inline style

```
    <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let data of allData">
        <div [innerHTML]="data.description"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you share the allData response?

Comment: I think, the accepted answer is wrong, @AbolfazlR's answer is right because you should never call a function from HTML you have to use Pipe .

Comment: for more information : https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bypass the Angular protection using DomSanitizer. DomSanitizer, a service of Angular helps to prevent attackers from injecting malicious client-side scripts into web pages.

```
 <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let data of allData">
     <div [innerHTML]="getData(data.description)"></div>
 </div>
```

in your .ts file

```
  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  getData(description) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(description);
  }
```

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xeuupi-ulwvem?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-overview-example.ts

Comment: thanks a for your help. Devang Patel.  appreciate

Answer (score 1):

do not forget to sanitize the received data, You can use the following `pipe` to sanitize your data :

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(content) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
  }
}
```

Then :

```
 <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let data of allData">
     <div [innerHTML]="data.description | safeHtml"></div>
 </div>
```

**NOTE:**

Add the `SafeHtmlPipe` pipe to the declarations section of your module